# Safari 'on hover' and 'click' error on image overlay

Tags: css, browser, safari, hover, compatibility

got this mysterious error on hover (and click) when i hover over an image in Safari 7.06 (haven't tested other versions). Other browsers doesn't seem to have this problem) This occurs only on the right column, it's a kind of masonry grid but can't find out what is going wrong..

Link: http://www.abouzahra.nl/interior-products/

Someone can figure this out? Would be great!

Hope you guys can help,

Cheers Joeri

Comment: No errors in Safari 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the `transition` in the default state and only toggle the `opacity` on `hover`. Also try having the default with an `opacity` of `1.0`.

```
.cols img {
  opacity: 1.0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.cols img:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```